# Is there a tradition of using mantras in Ayurveda?

Tags: scripture, mantras, ayurveda

Jyotish has a tradition of prescribing mantras as remedies to target a particular situation. Does Ayurveda have a similar tradition of prescribing mantras to remedy a particular condition of the physique?